# Using URL schemes to internally navigate an app

Tags: ios, architecture, url-scheme

I'm at the architecture planning stage of an iOS app. I've never used URL schemes before, but would like to incorporate them with this app.

This got me thinking. Instead of pushing and popping View Controllers from other View Controllers, what if I were to control the View state of my app internally using URL schemes. Specifically, building some sort of abstract manager that intercepts the URLs and displays the correct View Controller.

Basically, I'm looking for reasons that this isn't a good approach as I'm sure it violates MVC principles. The advantage I'm seeing is that if the app is built foundationally in this way, any view or state of view is accesible through a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Three20? It offers something similar. http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-URL-Based-Navigation

Comment: Yes, thats perfect. Thanks, Cyupa.

Comment: The link is broken now. Any other relevant link?

Comment: At this point, with the introduction of segues, it's kind of out of scope. You can have a look here: https://github.com/facebook/three20